# Create two separate windows in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, curses

Picture a terminal. There are two windows inside that terminal. One on top, one on bottom. The top one is much bigger. The top one receives asynchronous updates. The bottom one is for user input.

It would work almost exactly the same as vim - the text editor.

I'm writing this in Python. I'm guessing you would do this by using `curses`, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I didn't have any trouble understanding the question. Could be because I was looking for the same info a few months ago.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want the [python standard library implementation of ncurses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Yes, curses + some code that will do parallel stuff