# Is there a way to create a separate display and input on the same terminal using curse?

Tags: python, curses

I'd like to code a command line program that result in this UI:

```
------------
|          |
|     A    |
|__________|
|_____B____|
```

A is a separate process that loops and displays a list of real time events. It self-refresh.

B is a command prompt. It's fixed at the bottom and got a command history.

I know some command line IRC programs does this so it must be possible.

Bonus point if you can give me a snippet using a Python binding.

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639853/create-two-separate-windows-in-terminal) but I'm kind of lost in the curse documentation.

Comment: Might be worth trying it out with pymux: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/pymux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enventually I tried to do it with urwid which is way higher level than ncurse.

I asked a question about it on SO and didn't got more results.

But eventually I found some FOSS that did just that, I used the source code and made something that worked. You can find the answer in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635299/how-to-make-a-chat-like-ui-using-python-urwid/8636277#8636277).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`/Demo/curses/`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Demo/curses) directory of the python source code. It lists several intersting examples using the curses module that you can learn all you need from, and some more.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - this is a great implementation of the architecture you desire, written with urwid (an ncurses wrapper): http://zderadicka.eu/terminal-interfaces-in-python/#comment-123799

It took some tweaking to turn it into a chat client, but it's pretty simple to do so with pipes. The author's code is on github: https://github.com/izderadicka/xmpp-tester/blob/master/commander.py